# Impossible to add google account to iPhone

Tags: iphone, gmail

Since today my iPhone started asking my google password of my gmail account which was working yesterday.
After adding my password + 2FA I'm getting redirected to the add account screen.
Things I've tried :
- Delete & add gmail account
- Restart iPhone
- Swith wifi off and try with 4G
- Revoke access to all my authorized devices

I don't want to use any google app (Calendar, gmail).
Has anyone faced this issue recently ? I know it is wideaspread and happening from time to time. I've tried anything I read on many forums (including stackoverflow).
Would appreciate your help.

Best

Comment: Reading this question, I don't think that this fits on Stack Overflow, which is a programming Q&A. This doesn't look related to a personal code error, more like a software problem.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).